# Parent that only holds state and doesn't render for communication

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a reusable component that I can use to load ads via Doubleclick (DFP) asynchronously. The problem I'm running into is there are several dependencies before an ad can actually load, and I'm not sure the best way to handle the communication and sequence. Because the ad components render anywhere on the page and don't render as part of a parent, I'm not sure how to handle it since I can't embed ads inside of a parent to communicate.

In this article:
http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live

There is this potential solution, but after some searching I wasn't able to find an example that doesn't tie the rendering together.

> > "If you can't find a component where it makes sense to own the state, create a new component simply for holding the state and add it somewhere in the hierarchy above the common owner component."

Here are the details/steps:

1). I first need to load the JS http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
This creates a global googletag object.

2). I need to set global targeting (i.e. site name, content type, etc) that will apply to all ad tags (configurable).

**Example**

```
    googletag.pubads().setTargeting('site', window.location.hostname);
```

3). I need to define the ad slots and targeting for individual ad slots that React rendered.

```
    googletag.defineSlot('/12345/zone', [[300, 250], [300, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-300x250-0').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('pos', 'sidebar_300_1');
```

4). I need to specify settings globally

```
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
```

5). I need to render the ad slots (with the option to render individually or globally)

```
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.display(divIdAttribute);
    });
```

or just

```
googletag.display();
```

I Initially created two components: a DFPManager that loads the required Javascript once, and then a DFPAd that actually handles the individual ads. I couldn't figure out the communication.

I also need to be able to reload individual ads based on external events (i.e. ajax page change) or create new ads as a user scrolls into infinite scroll content.

Is the best solution to manage my own events system where I put listeners in my components to depend on external events, or is there a better way to manage this? In that case I wouldn't necessarily need a DFPManager since no rendering takes place there and I could trigger an event when ready. This is a similar problem for analytics tracking where I need to track pageviews based on external events, but only after first loading an initial javascript (i.e. Google Analytics tracking js).

```
<div id="300-250-ad"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    React.renderComponent(
        <DFPAd size={[[300, 250], [300, 600]]} targeting={[["pos", "sidebar_300_1"]]} />,
        document.getElementById('300-250-ad')
    );
</script>
```

I may be overthinking this. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you manage to write this reusable component ? can you share ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning DFPManager into just an object which fires change events sounds like a good plan. It wouldn't be a React component itself any more. The individual ad components could accept the store object as a prop, then subscribe to the change events in componentDidMount, and unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount. The onChange handler could call setState with the current data from the store, which will trigger a re-render.

The store could be implemented like the store in the [Flux TodoMVC](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-todo-list.html) example, which uses an EventEmitter base class. If there is no interactivity, using a full dispatcher is probably overkill, since there won't be any user actions by the sounds of it.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas. I also found an example on DOM Event Listeners that seems to recommend a similar setup. http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html Appreciate the help.